# Images changing on scroll and fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I’m using fullPage.js(https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) and I need to have on the second section a scroll with images changing like a movie (Like this http://www.newjumoconcept.com/en/).

I’ve added a class ‘sprites’ to the second section and stoped the fullPage scroll with: normalScrollElements: '.sprites', and the idea is to delete the class when the scroll event is finished so that fullPage continues the normal scroll to the next section.

I’ve been reading similar questions about changing images on scroll but I can’t get it to work, and I have no idea of how to delete the class when the scroll is finished.

That’s what I have:

html:

```
<section id="second" class="section sprites">
    <div id="sprites"></div>
</section>
```

css:

```
#sprites > img:first-child {
opacity: 1;
-ms-filter: none;
filter: none;
}
#sprites > img {
opacity: 0;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        ...
        normalScrollElements: '.sprites',
        ...
    });
    preload();
    $('#sprites').on('mousewheel', function(event, index) {
        switchImage();
    });
});
var pics = []; 
function preload(){
    for(i = 1; i < 23; i++) {
        pics[i] = new Image();
        pics[i].src = "i+".jpg"; 
        jQuery('#sprites').append('<img class="sprite" src="' + pics[i].src +'">');
    }
};
function switchImage() {
    var s = jQuery(window).scrollTop()/10;
    var index = Math.floor(s/5);
    jQuery('.sprite').css('opacity','0');
    jQuery('.sprite').eq(index).css('opacity','1');
}
```

And I'm using jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin(Brandon Aaron).

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the callbacks provided by fullPage.js such as [`afterLoad` or `onSlideLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks).

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
     afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
         var loadedSection = $(this);

         //section 3 finished loading
         if (index == 3) {
             $('#myElement').addClass('demo');

             $('#myElement2').removeClass('demo');
         }

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alvaro, I finally got it working with a combination of your sugestion and this plugin:
https://github.com/ghepting/javascript-video-scrubber

In case anyone is looking for something like this.